# Unexpected behavior of PasteButton

Tags: front-end, palettes

Assume the following very complex palette:

```
CreatePalette[
  PasteButton[FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
];
```

Its purpose is to insert a `FontColor` rule. It works like expected in a notebook but I plan to use it inside raw cell expressions. Please try the following two examples. Paste the following code into a notebook

```
NotebookWrite[
 SelectedNotebook[],
 Cell[Cell["abc", "Text"]]
 ]
```

You get a text cell saying "abc". Now go with the cursor anywhere between the "abc" and press `Ctrl+Shift+E` (this is *Cell->Show Expression*) to see the underlying cell data. Go directly in front of the last closing bracket, make a comma and press the palette-button. You should get

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox["abc", Text]],FontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0]]
```

Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+E` again and the text is red. Works like a charm. Now try the following cell with the same approach:

```
NotebookWrite[
 SelectedNotebook[],
 Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"]]
 ]
```

Here I get (Linux 64, Mma 8.0.4)

```
Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"],
  RowBox[{"FontColor", "->", RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[", 
  RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], "]"}]}]
]
```

which is not what I expected and which does not work.

**Question:** Can anyone explain me what's going on here? Is the `PasteButton` aware of the context?

**Background:** The background is, that I have created a palette which I want to use to adjust style-sheet definitions. That was, when I stumbled over this behaviour.

**Fix:** One possible way to fix this is to use `NotebookWrite` directly instead of the `PasteButton`. Disadvantage of this approach is, that the expression can no longer be inserted into a normal notebook, because there you have to insert cell-expression.

Comment: It's very weird. Bug? It doesn't like StyleData cells it tries to paste it as a box expressions

Comment: Maybe the magic word is "effectively" here: You could use the option `BaseStyle->"Paste"` and a normal `Button` and you get the same weird behavior. The doc of "Paste" says "effectively use NotebookApply upon the current selection using the button label as the applied data".

Comment: @halirutan You could try `Button["paste FontColor", Paste[Defer[FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]]]`.

Comment: @Heike This seems to work like I had hoped. Do you have an idea, why and when (even with the `Defer`) the translation from `->` to `\[Rule]` happens? It seems that wrapping `InputForm` around it always keeps the `->` form.

Comment: Bug.  Report it to tech support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the pasting which is attempting to be smart about what to paste, since in the case of pasting into a cell you actually write the box expressions, while when you are working with the cell expression you want the input-form inserted. In any case, this seems to work in both cases:

```
 CreatePalette[
 Button["Font Color", 
    NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], ToBoxes[FontColor -> RGBColor[1,0,0]]]
 ]]
```

Playing around with this I saw no problems with using it in a normal notebook. If it does cause problems with your other code please post code describing the issues.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what I had as work-around too.